# How do I debug stalled out package verification?

Tags: macos, install, package-management

Every time I try to install any new software this happens...

[image: Endlessly Verifying]

The package starts verifying, but then makes no progress.  Eventually I give up and cancel the install.  How can I diagnose this so I can start doing new things with my computer again?

I've tried examining the Console, but I see no related error messages.

Comment: I would google install pkg from the command line in debug mode.

Comment: `sudo installer -pkg [PACKAGE].pkg -target [TARGET]`